# Return a string from class — weird behavior

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I was a little into c++ coding 10 years or so ago but never really fell in love with it. But I need c++ now for one of my projects (so I have a little understanding of c++ but I am no deep expert). I went through my old notes and code snippets and got the code doing what I want — except for one thing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class B
{
    private:
        string ns;

    public:
        B(string ms) {ns = ms;}
        string gets() {return ns;}
};

class A
{
    private:
        vector<B> nb;

    public:
        A(vector<B> mb) {nb = mb;}
        vector<B> getb() {return nb;}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    B b0 = B("zero");
    B b1 = B("one");
    B b2 = B("two");
    B b3 = B("three");
    A a = A({b0, b1, b2, b3});

    cout << endl << endl;

    for(auto it = a.getb().begin(); it != a.getb().end(); ++it)
        cout << it->gets() << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Running this code (g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp) results in a

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>   what():  std::bad_alloc Aborted (core dumped)

error. This is already weird as this is basically just a copy from my notes (however, it returns an integer in the notes and not a string). If I instead let the function return `ns.c_str()` it almost works and I get

> �qi one two three

Interestingly, this just happens in the loop. Using `(a.getb().begin())->gets()` gives me the correct value ("zero"). What is the explanation for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `getb()` in `a.getb().begin()` and `a.getb().end()` returns a separate copy of the original vector. Comparing iterators from one vector with iterators from another vector is bad.

You could change your `getb()` method to something like this.

`const vector<B>& getb() const {return nb;}`

And now the `begin()` and `end()` calls would be working on the same vector.

Or use the more c++11 friendly range-based for loop:

```
for (var b in a.getb()) {
    cout << b.gets() << " ";
```

Which does the `.begin()`, `.end()`, and `++` for you.

If you absolutely want to use the old-style for loop, instead of changing your `getb()` method, you could also do:

```
auto b_copy = a.getb();
for(auto it = b_copy.begin(); it != b_copy.end(); ++it)
    cout << it->gets() << " ";
```

Comment: `for (B &b :  a.getb())` would also solve the problem